# Electronics Design Challenges/Competitions

Tags: design

Is anyone aware of some website that keeps an up to date list of running hardware, electronics or electrical design competitions/challenges/contests? I am looking for the types of things that a hobbyist would enter - not something where university researchers compete for large funding.

An example would be something like the [AVR Hero](https://www.facebook.com/AtmelCorporation?sk=app_403834839671843&brandloc=DISABLE&app_data=dlt-1) contest.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic but might be more at home on this site's [Meta site](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/), or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Answer (score 2):

Many appear un Circuit Cellar magazine, either sponsored be the mag, or sometimes in advertisements.